# MySQL:-Displaying results in a single row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which is working fine but the results are displaying in multiple columns.
     [image: Query with result.]

But I want the results into a single row like

```
closed Open Cancelled
  2      1      3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GROUP BY` clause will return one row for each value grouped by. Since you have three material_status values you are getting three rows returned. Simply remove that clause and you will get one line in the results since all of your columns are aggregate.

```
SELECT SUM...
FROM purchase_order
```

The `ORDER BY` clause is also not necessary since you are only returning one row.

Comment: One more question is how to differentiate this result based upon the year wise ?

Comment: Add a year column to the SELECT clause and then GROUP BY the same year column.  If it's a date column you might have something like `SELECT YEAR(date), SUM... FROM purchase_order GROUP BY YEAR(date)`.